# Apache Permissions

Tags: apache, file-permissions

I am having some trouble setting the permissions on an Apache Server (Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS). I moved the directory to my home directory.  I was able to give apache permissions to that directory. But, it didn't apply to the sub directories.

Is there a way to apply permissions to all the subfolders?

I am fairly new to Ubuntu Server and would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chown -R www-data:www-data /home/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown

Also you can try what @mjgpy3 suggested

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
chmod -R <mode> <root>
```

This will recursively change permissions from a `<root>` to every sub directory and file. Be very careful setting the `<mode>` though. `<mode>` is an a number between 000 and 777 specifying mode and `<root>` is the parent of all files/folders that you want to change the permission of.

**UPDATE**

To specify `<mode>` you will, as I said above need to provide a 3 digit number, each of which is 0-7 inclusively. Each of these numbers specifies a different group (if you will). The first means current user, the second means a user's group and the third means the rest of the world. Now, the actual numbers themselves specify which privilege their respective group will be granted; this is done in binary. RWE (read, write and execute) are the available permissions on a file.

So, consider the number 5.

5 in binary is 101, this means that 5 specifies R-E, which means read, not execute and write. As you can see a 1 indicates that a privilege is enabled, whereas a 0 means disabled.

So, here are some common uses and what they mean:

```
chmod 777 file.txt
```

`file.txt` is now readable, writeable and executable by everyone who may ever come across the file.

A more used example is:

```
chmod 755 file.txt
```

This says that (since 7 is 111 in binary) the owner of the file (that's probably you) can do anything they want with it, I.E RWE, I.E. read, write and execute. Where those who are not the user may only read and execute it.

Here's an [external source](http://www.pageresource.com/cgirec/chmod.htm) if my explanation did not make sense to you.

Comment: What do I put in the <mode> variable?